# How to make edittext above soft input keyboard always in android?

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

I hava a listview in my layout, the lastest item is a edittext and the other are textviews, when user input message into edittext and click ensure button right of edittext, the listview will display the message with textview above edittext.

The problem is the edittext support consecutive input, when i input multiple message and submit each other, the keyboard of soft input shade from my edittext, how can i make the edittext above the keyboard always? thx for your help!

Comment: Are you using a Linearlayout?

Comment: I use a framelayout, the edittext is a item of listview

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these statements to your **activity** declaration in your **manifest.xml** file.

```
    <activity
        android:name="packageName.activityName"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Good luck.